# Build Failed whenever I try to run the app

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.6.10"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.googleassistantclone"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.googleassistantclone"
        minSdk = 25
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }


}



dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-components:17.1.5")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    val lifecycle_version = "2.6.2"
    val arch_version = "2.2.0"
    val room_version = ("2.6.1")

    // ViewModel
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // LiveData
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")

    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version")

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version")

    // Annotation processor
    annotationProcessor ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version")
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version")

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version")

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version")

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData

    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")

    // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation ("androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version")

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
//    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
//    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version")
    implementation ("the.bot.box:horoscope-api:1.0.2")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version")
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version")
    // optional - Test helpers
    implementation ("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1")
//    testImplementation ("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")

    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:19.0.0")
    implementation ("com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0")
//    implementation ("com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0")
//    implementation ("com.github.shubham0204:Text2Summary-Android:alpha-05")
//    implementation ("com.github.KwabenBerko:OpenWeatherMap-Android-Library:2.1.0")
//    implementation ("the.bot.box:horoscope-api:1.0.2")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1")
    implementation ("com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3")


}
```

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.6.10" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.6.10" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false

}
buildscript{
    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies{
        val kotlin_version = "1.6.10"
        classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0")
        classpath ("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
        classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
        classpath ("com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3")
        classpath ("com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5")
    }
}
```

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
}



dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
//        maven("https://dl.bintary.com/wotomas/maven")
//        maven("https://maven.google.com")
//        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/boxbotbarry/maven")
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Google Assistant Clone"
include(":app")
```

These are my gradle file, I was making a Google Assistant Project and was using ksp instead of kapt but there is error in both.

e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'kotlin.sequences.Sequence com.google.devtools.ksp.processing.Resolver.getPackagesWithAnnotation(java.lang.String)'
at androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspRoundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(KspRoundEnv.kt:107)
at androidx.room.compiler.processing.CommonProcessorDelegate.processRound(XBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:100)
at androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspBasicAnnotationProcessor.process(KspBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:62)
at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension$doAnalysis$6$1.invoke(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:291)
at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension$doAnalysis$6$1.invoke(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:289)
at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.handleException(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:394)
at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.doAnalysis(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:289)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:123)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:257)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:42)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:248)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:88)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Execution failed for task ':app:kspDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

These two are error occurring. If anyone can understand please help me.

Comment: 1 issue: you are using Kotlin 1.6 but KSP 1.8, those versions should match. i.e. use 1.8 everywhere